# Android - Can not change GUI from a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

long time watcher, first time writer :P

I got this problem:

I can't seem to change anything that has to do with the layout of android from my playSoundThread. 
In this example, I use EventListeners. I already tried the simple way. I passed the ScrollView through, so that the thread can change it. But when it's happening, the thread stops immediately. And even when I use EventListeners, the same Problem occurs.
Changing a variable and posting log information works fine, but not layout Objects.

The first thing is, that I want to scroll a HorizontalScrollView from out the Thread's run() method.
the second case is, that, if the thread comes to it's end, I wanna fire an "i'm finished"-Event and change the image and function of an ImageButton

Here's the run()-method of the thread

```
public void run() {
if(this.playbackPosition < rhythm.tracks.get(0).sounds.size()) {
            for (Track t : rhythm.tracks) {
                if (t.sounds.get(this.playbackPosition).equals("1")) {
                    this.sp.play(t.SoundID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                }
            }
            this.playbackPosition++;
            if ( this.playbackPosition >= (this.scrollIndex*(192/this.zoom)) ){

                this.scrollIndex++;
//Here I wanna fire the "Scroll" event
                    for(ScrollListener sl : scrollListeners){
                      sl.update(scrollPositions[scrollIndex]);
                }
        }


        }
//This is the point where the playback is finished and the event to change a button is fired
            else {
                    tmpListener.update();
                 }
            }
        }
```

The declaration of the OnPlaybackFinishedListener can be found in the class Player, which is the parent of the PlaySoundThread:

```
public void addOnPlaybackFinishedListener(){
        tmpListener = new OnPlaybackFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void update() {
                scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
//this is a seconds Listener, which was implemented to test, if the problem still occurs with a little listener chain
                shutdownListener.update();
            }
        };
    }


public void addShutdownListener(OnExecutorShutdown sl){
        this.shutdownListener = sl;
    }
```

And here's the part of the MainActivity which is the parent class of Player and adds the shutdown listener and the ScrollListener:

```
awesomePlayer.addScrollListener(new ScrollListener(){
            public void update(int position){
                Log.i("ScrollListener update()","Running ScrollTo( "+position+", "+VIEW_rhythmscroll.getScrollY()+")");
                VIEW_rhythmscroll.scrollTo(position, VIEW_rhythmscroll.getScrollY());
            }
        });

        awesomePlayer.addOnPlaybackFinishedListener();
        awesomePlayer.addShutdownListener(new OnExecutorShutdown() {    
            @Override
            public void update() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//This method changes the Pause Button to a Play Button with a new OnClickListener and a new Picture
                BUTTON_STOP.performClick();
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help? Is there another way to avoid this problem? I'm developing on Android 2.2
Is it even possible to access UI elements from a thread?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify UI elements from a seperate thread, UI elements have to be modified from the main, UI `Thread`.  There are a lot of topics on this, but you can update the UI by using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s `onPostExecute()`, `onPreExecute()`, or `onProgressUpdate()` methods, the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class's  `runOnUiThread(Runnable action)`, or by sending a `Message` to a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. These are some helpful keywords :)